# Typescript generic type inference based on inheritance

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Consider this code:

```
class A<T> { t?: T; }
interface B {}
class C implements A<B> {}
function f<T1 extends A<T2>, T2>(a: T1): T2 | undefined { return a.t; }

const result = f(new C());
const result2 = f(new A<B>());
```

It turns out that the type of `result` or even `result2` will be `unknown`, while it can be inferred from the context, as `C` is implementing `A<B>` (so it can be inferred as `B`).

Why typescript does not do that? Is it a missing feature, a non-sound inference or is there another way to achieve desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find my own answer, and I have to say TypeScript is flawless!

```
class A<T> { t?: T; }
interface B {}
class C extends A<B> {}

type ExtractGeneric<T> = T extends A<infer X> ? X : never;
function f<T1 extends A<T2>, T2 = ExtractGeneric<T1>>(a: T1): T2 | undefined { return a.t; }

const result = f(new C());
const result2 = f(new A<B>());
```

Comment: It would be appreciated if someone could explain why this inference is not done by default.

Comment: Its not done as it is just second argument. There is really revert relation, you say that the first argument depends on the second. Take into consideration that TS is not able to infer T2 as there is no demands for this type, TS does not perform relation between arguments if you dont do that explicitly. And explicitly you have relation from T1 to  T2, but not in other way round